# Java thread switching

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that is supposed to run multiple threads at the same time.

It's a simulation of the card game Uno, and you're supposed to have a thread for each player.

Now here's the catch: whenever a player has a card with the same number and color of the card on top of the dump in hand but it's not this player's turn, he can 'cut' the line and put the card down. The player next to the player who cut the line then continues.

I have a class Player :

```
class Player implements Runnable {

    public boolean isHisTurn = false;

    public Thread makeMove(final Card topCard, final boolean isHisTurn) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }
}
```

thread.start() then starts the run method, where I have my logic and decision making. At the beggining of run() the thread sleeps for a random of 300 - 700 miliseconds, as to make cutting line possible in this time frame.

My question is, should I store the threads somewhere, and if so, where, and how can I switch between threads when it's a different player's turn? I know it has something to do with boolean isHisTurn, I just don't know how to use it.

And yes, it is homework, but I'm only asking for a small piece of it, I don't want a complete answer, just something to push me in the right direction.

Comment: I doubt this should have multiple threads.  Instead, one thread performs one 'turn at a time', taking the card from whatever player can provide it.

Comment: You need some kind monitor for each Thread, that allows you to tell the Thread whose turn it is that they can run. This will stop all the other threads from executing until you tell them that they can. Take a look at [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: You're doing this wrong. You don't want to start a new thread for every move. You might want to have a separate thread per player, although I don't know that there's any strong motivation for that either.

Comment: What if I put the threads in ArrayList and used join()?

Comment: @EJP makeMove method is only called once for each player

Comment: @Thompson, he's marked it as homework. Likely this is an introduction to threads, hence the thin motivation.

Comment: I suggest that the `makeMove()` method is called once per *move,* unless you have radically misnamed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and how can I switch between threads when it's a different player's turn?

The distinguishing feature of threads is that several threads can run at the same time. If you don't use that feature, there is no point in using threads. Since a player can also move when it isn't his turn, it actually makes sense that all players are active at the same time. Therefore, I'd create (and start) a single thread per player. That thread would alternate between sleeping and moving.

That leaves the question of how the threads can interact. For that, I'd create a class like:

```
class Game {
    Card topCard;
    Player nextPlayer;

    ...
}
```

and give the instance of game to each player thread. When the playing thread is thinking about his move, he can look at the top card, and whether it is his turn. When making his move, he simply updates the fields in the Game instance.

Of course, since different threads can be active at the same time, it is possible that two players try to move at the same time (or put differently, a player may decide to play a card, but another player is faster, making the initial player's move no longer valid). This is easiest prevented by synchronizing access to the `Game` instance. For realism, you might be tempted to synchronize when looking at the game state, then think, and then synchronize again to make the move. However, it might be easier to synchronize over the entire "look, think and move" cycle, because that ensures that players don't interfere with each others thinking, and reduces the number of corner cases you need to handle.

Another wrinkle is termination. The game ends as soon as the first player has no cards left, so the other players need a way to notice that fact. The easiest is probably for the finishing player to declare himself the winner (for instance, by setting a field `winningPlayer` in the `Game` instance) and for the other threads to terminate as soon as a winner is declared.

Comment: Synchronizing on 'Game' for each player's entire turn, is not correct -- other players can "cut in" if they can & do put down a match card, and the turn then shifts on from them.

Comment: You misunderstand: I said the threads "alternate between sleeping and moving", and I recommend to synchronize over the entire move sequence, which consists of "look, think and move". (Thinking isn't an euphemism for sleeping, but refers to the code that decides how the player will move.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help with a homework question because usually the professor is looking for a certain kind of solution and solving the problem correctly but in the wrong way can still be counted against you.  Saying you are supposed to have one thread per player, for example, is very helpful because there are many other valid ways of doing it but if you did it that way it would be wrong for your homework.  So if you have other information to share about the expected solution, please share it.  I think this problem was chosen because you haven't gotten to waiting on semaphores yet.

If you are going to have a thread per player then you can model the program on how human players would play.  Each player is aware of the card on top of the dump, who the other players are, what order they play in, who played last and what they played.  So you want to represent all those facts in some objects that all the threads can see.

Each thread (player) also has its own hand that only it can see, so that should be modeled as an object per thread.

The key thing is that the players (threads) make the moves!  Your main program just starts the threads and waits for the game to finish.  The players can just sleep for random amounts of time, then wake up, see if they can move, move if they can, and then go back to sleep.